# Как сделать единый обработчик для всех путей Django

Tags: django

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Django написать обработчик для всех путей, чтобы пользователь вводил url, например, site.ru/test, а django рендерит главную страницу вместо этого, если такого пути не указано в urls.py

Comment: мидлварь написать

Comment: Можно последним элементом urlpatterns установить универсальный url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два пути решения данной задачи:

1. Установить обработчик 404 ошибки.

*# project/urls.py*

```
handler404 = 'my_app.views.handler404'
```

*# my_app/views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def handler404(request):
    response = render(request, '404.html')
    response.status_code = 200 # Или 404, как по душе... 
    return response
```

2. Установить "универсальный url " в конце списка Ваших url.

*# project/urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [ ...,

        path("*", my_app.views.universal_answer, name='universal_answer')
    ]
```

*# my_app/views.py*

```
def universal_answer(request):
    response = render(request, 'universal_answer.html')
    return response
```